# Convert integer numeric interval to regex

Tags: regex, algorithm

SO,

I'm looking for a solution about the problem - how to convert integer interval to regex. Suppose I have two numbers, `A` and `B`. Both of them are positive integers and let be `A < B`

Now, I'm looking for algorithm (may be code) that will result in a single regex, that will match numbers between `A` and `B` (borders included). For example, I have `A=20`, `B=35`, then the correct regex is `^2[0-9]$|^3[0-5]$` - since only numbers 20..35 will fit to it.

In common case, when `A` is something like 83724 and `B` is something like 28543485 it's not so obvious, however.

upd. Mostly, it is a *curiosity* matter. I **know** the best way to do this: return result: `A<=X && X<=B`

Comment: I don't think regular expressions are the best and easiest solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes, I know that direct comparison will be much easier. In my case, it's a matter of some 'comfort'.

Comment: Example http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo. In fact you will loose some comfort, if at all you successfully create a regex for this. You would be better off with using normal range check.

Comment: @Qtax - if I want result itself, your suggestion would be great. But I want algorithm itself

Comment: This is like asking a carpenter how to use a screwdriver to hammer in a nail. You may be able to do it, but it's the wrong tool for the job and the carpenter will laugh at you.

Comment: Incidentally, the regex you've written doesn't quite work. `|` has a low precedence. For example, the string `240` will match the regex because it matches `/^2[0-9]/`. Similarly, `132` will match because it matches `/3[0-5]$/`. If you insist on using regexes, then it should be `/^(2[0-9]|3[0-5])$/`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe - I mistyped, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use regex in this situation?

I would just do this:

`boolean isBetween = num > A && num < B;`

(Code written in Java)

Far easier, a regex like what you're asking for could be huge and using it in this situation would be pointless and inefficient.

Good Luck.

If you truly insist on using RegEx for this task, see [this website](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range), run the regex with verbose mode on and it will explain to you how the author's RegEx works.

Comment: Yet again, I'm aware of this. It's not a question about why should I do this :p It's a question about - how can I do this :p

Comment: This is a comment at best, not an answer.

Comment: @JamesWilliams - good for me, thanks (I'm trying to understand, not to get a single result, so that verbose mode is awesome)

Answer (score 2):

As others have already told you, this is not a very good idea. It will not be faster than just matching all integers and filter them afterwards. But I will answer your question anyway.

Depending on how large the interval is you can let the regex engine optimize it for you, so you just output a `|`-separated list of values. This can be minimized algorithmically with basic algorithms from finite automata theory.

This may be too memory-intensive for large intervals. In that case you can match all numbers of different lengths from A and B in one go. In your example, all numbers of 6-7 digits are easily matched with `[0-9][1-9]{5,6}`. Now you have the border cases left, which you can create recursively by (for the A side in this case, I have not included the base case of the recursion):

1. Let S be A.
2. Let f be first digit of S, `g=f+1`, and n be `(digits of S)-1`
3. Add a segment to the regex for digits larger than f of: `[g-9][0-9]{n}`
4. Add a segment for numbers starting with f: `f(recursive call starting from step 2, with S=the rest of digits of S)`

So for `A=123` we would end up with something like (spaces only added for "readability"):

```
([2-9][0-9]{2}) | (1(([3-9][0-9]{1}) | (2(([4-9]) | 3))) )
```

Comment: I'm curious why you decided to use recursion. You can do this iteratively pretty intuitively:
`([2-9][0-9]{2} | 1[3-9][0-9]{1} | 12[4-9] | 123)`

Comment: Recursion is more natural to me. But you are right, by keeping the entire prefix we can do it iteratively with the same kind of algorithm.

Comment: I also just realized that my recursive algorithm gives a DFA, while rolius example needs an NFA to resolve. If this makes any difference at all depends on the regex engine, but a naive engine wouldn't need any backtracking to match my pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I've done with this (in PHP):

```
class Converter
{
    const REGEXP_OR     = '|';
    const REGEXP_START  = '^';
    const REGEXP_END    = '$';

    protected $sStart;
    protected $sEnd;
    function __construct($mStart, $mEnd=null)
    {
        if(is_array($mStart) && count($mStart)>1)
        {
            $this->sStart = (string)($mStart[0]);
            $this->sEnd   = (string)($mStart[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->sStart = (string)($mStart);
            $this->sEnd   = (string)($mEnd);
        }
        if((int)($mStart)>(int)($mEnd))
        {
            $this->sStart = $this->sEnd = null;
        }
    }

    public function getRegexp()
    {
        return self::REGEXP_START.$this->_get_regexp_by_range($this->sStart, $this->sEnd).self::REGEXP_END;
    }

    protected function _get_regexp_by_range($sStart, $sEnd, $sOr=self::REGEXP_OR, $sFrom=self::REGEXP_START, $sTill=self::REGEXP_END)
    {
       if(!isset($sStart) || !isset($sEnd))
       {
           return null;
       }
       if((int)($sStart)>(int)($sEnd))
       {
          return null;
       }
       elseif($sStart==$sEnd)
       {
          return $sStart;
       }
       elseif(strlen($sEnd)>strlen($sStart))
       {
          $rgRegexp  = array($this->_get_regexp_by_range($sStart, str_repeat('9', strlen($sStart))));
          for($i=strlen($sStart)+1; $i<strlen($sEnd)-1; $i++)
          {
             $rgRegexp[] = $this->_get_regexp_by_range('1'.str_repeat('0', $i), str_repeat('9', $i+1));
          }
          $rgRegexp[] = $this->_get_regexp_by_range('1'.str_repeat('0', strlen($sEnd)-1), $sEnd);
          return join($sTill.$sOr.$sFrom, $rgRegexp);
       }
       else
       {
          $rgRegexp   = array();
          for($iIntersect=0;$iIntersect<strlen($sStart);$iIntersect++)
          {
             if($sStart[$iIntersect]!=$sEnd[$iIntersect])
             {
                break;
             }
          }
          if($iIntersect)
          {
             return join($sTill.$sOr.$sFrom, array_map(function($sItem) use ($iIntersect, $sStart)
             {
                return substr($sStart, 0, $iIntersect).$sItem;
             }, explode($sTill.$sOr.$sFrom, $this->_get_regexp_by_range(substr($sStart, $iIntersect), substr($sEnd, $iIntersect)))));
          }
          else
          {
             $rgRegexp = array($sStart);
             for($iPos=strlen($sStart)-1; $iPos>0; $iPos--)
             {
                if($sStart[$iPos]+1<10)
                {
                   $rgRegexp[]=substr($sStart, 0, $iPos).'['.($sStart[$iPos]+1).'-'.'9'.']'.str_repeat('[0-9]', strlen($sStart)-$iPos-1);
                }
             }
             if(($sStart[0]+1)<($sEnd[0]-1))
             {
                $rgRegexp[]='['.($sStart[0]+1).'-'.($sEnd[0]-1).']'.str_repeat('[0-9]', strlen($sStart)-1);
             }
             elseif((int)($sStart[0])+1==(int)($sEnd[0])-1)
             {
                $rgRegexp[]=($sStart[0]+1).str_repeat('[0-9]', strlen($sStart)-1);
             }
             for($iPos=1; $iPos<strlen($sEnd); $iPos++)
             {
                if($sEnd[$iPos]-1>=0)
                {
                  $rgRegexp[]=substr($sEnd,0, $iPos).'['.'0'.'-'.($sEnd[$iPos]-1).']'.str_repeat('[0-9]', strlen($sEnd)-$iPos-1);
                }
             }
             $rgRegexp[]=$sEnd;
             return join($sTill.$sOr.$sFrom, $rgRegexp);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

then, it get correct results with any strings, but I think the resulting regex is not the best one.

```
$sPattern = (new Converter('1', '1000000000'))->getRegexp();
var_dump(
   preg_match('/'.$sPattern.'/', '10000000000'), 
   preg_match('/'.$sPattern.'/', '100000000'));
```

anyway, thanks a lot to all who answered.