# Comparison operators in regex

Tags: php, regex

Can we use comparison in a regex pattern? I want to check if a recent matched group is `greater than` a number. This is the pattern: `size=(\d+)` and I wanna see if `(\d+)>200` then return true.

Comment: That's not a regular expression anymore, that's a programming language. So: no.

Comment: Not like that I think. But you could match everything that is up to 200.

Comment: You could emulate that with something like `([0-9]{2,}|[2-9])[0-9][0-9]`

Comment: @revo yesterday I resolved similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374231/convert-integer-numeric-interval-to-regex but note: it is sad to use regex for that. **Use normal comparison**

Comment: @SmokeyPHP That won't match "1111"... :)

Comment: @deceze Yea, I've updated it

Comment: @Smokey That'll match "0000", which is not "> 200"... ;)

Comment: @deceze yea, fixed it again but in my answer - can't edit my comment anymore

Comment: @revo I hope I'm properly using Smokey here to demonstrate that regexen aren't the ideal tool to do this... ;)

Comment: @deceze Indeed - I in no way suggest that regex is the best tool for the job, but rather wanted to prove that this particular example is possible with regex. I have tried to improve my stance on this in my answer. (I like regex challenges)

Comment: the problem is that i'm using regex in `htaccess` so no programming language allowed! but as u know regular expression are similar in each language I tagged PHP too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it with that same syntax, but what you're after is possible with a more complex expression such as:

Greater than 200:

```
([1-9]\d+|(?!200)[2-9])\d\d
```

Include 200:

```
([1-9]\d+|[2-9])\d\d
```

As you approach other (and larger) numbers, however, it will be unmanagable.

You would do best to match all numbers, then loop through the results to do the `> 200` check, and remove ones that don't comply.

**Note: The above regular expressions are just to show that matching numbers greater than 200 is possible in pure regex. It is not recommended however, and more complex/variable numbers will be unworkable.**

OP mentioned in comments that they would like to match `> 30*1024*1024`, which is `> 31457280`

In the name of proving why regex is a pain, I have written the required pattern:

```
\b((3[1-9][4-9][5-9][7-9][2-9][8-9]\d+)|(3[1-9][4-9][5-9][7-9][3-9]\d{2,})|(3[1-9][4-9][5-9][8-9]\d{3,})|(3[1-9][4-9][6-9]\d{4,})|(3[1-9][5-9]\d{5,})|(3[2-9]\d{6,})|(?!31457280)(4\d{7,}))\b
```

(not very pretty!)

Comment: @deceze Fixed. Again :p

Comment: It matches 200, should only match > 200... ;P

Comment: *wipes sweat from brow* - fixed again... @deceze you're a slave driver! (at least NOW it's correct... I think) :)

Comment: LOL - You're enslaving yourself by attempting this task in the first place... ;)

Comment: @deceze Yea I know, I just like the challenge. I have of course provided the (more manageable) alternative of looping through the results of any number group, but regex patterns are fun! (though that opinion may not be shared by many..)

Comment: +1 so I was going to match greater than 30*1024*1024. then that's not possible?

Comment: @revo It'll be possible... but won't look great - is that what you're after? Numbers greater than 31457280 ?  Note that solutions like this are number specific and must be crafted per number (hence all the notes about regex not being the right tool for the job)

Comment: actully that number is not fixed and may change in future. Ohhh regex..!

Comment: @revo I actually managed to create a regex for that number, however this will need to keep being done every time it changes. I would have to question the reasons and system process - maybe your htaccess could redirect the request to your PHP script no matter that number pattern it is, then do the check in the PHP file (if it doesn't match, throw a 404)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, the purpose of the regular expressions is to match expresions not to program with it