# Regular expression number range

Tags: regex

I have a query about regular expression number range.

1. 15 to infinity?
2. 20 to infinity?

I know 10 to infinity -> `[1-9][0-9]+` or `[1-9][0-9]*` works.

Thanks.
B

Comment: For 15, just use `OR` logic: e.g. `1[5-9]|[2-9]\d|\d{3,}` - matches 15-19, or 20-99, or any number of 3 or more digits. 20 is similar but easier as it's basically the same as 10

Comment: `[1-9][0-9]*` will also match 1-9 no? `*` is 0 or more

Comment: Why regular expression though? I have a feeling this could be [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve? And in what language?

Comment: This is generally a bad idea, as regular expression deal with _text_, not _number_. Try to do this in whatever programming language you're using.

Comment: Will the proposed regexs really match [infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity)?

Comment: @devnull I don't think this is really the time for literal meanings, as I'm pretty sure the OP just means big numbers... but provided the machine and software running the regex had limitless capabilities, theoretically they could! (match *up to* infinity, that is, not match infinity)

Comment: Thanks SmokeyPHP, your initial comment did the trick. The syntax makes sense. The app is using perl, where perl is using a patterns file (containing reg ex) on a log file to make decisions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. I've faced this in [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374231/convert-integer-numeric-interval-to-regex) - and I ended with valid code which produces regex for range (i.e. `[a, b]`).

Your question could be simple resolved: your condition is `[a, b] U (b, +inf)` , where `b` is the highest number, combined with `9` only and have same count of digits as `a`. I.e. for 15 `b` will be `99`, for 300 `b` will be 999 e t.c. Second part `(b, +inf)` is an easy part - it's just `[1-9][0-9]{c, }` where `c` is count of digits in `b`.

So, to make a long story short:

- Find `c`. It;s just `string_length(a)` (it's not a real function, it's pseudo)
- Find `b`. It's just `repeat_string('9', c)` (it's not a real function, it's pseudo)
- Find first part of regex: [a, b] - you can see logic in my question (other answers there are good too)
- Build second part of your regex: `(b, +inf)`.
- Gather your two parts

But. For me it was a curiosity matter, while in the real situation: **do not use regex for this**. Simple `$x>a` check is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already, regex is not the tool for number comparisons - especially as your native language has a MUCH simpler alternative that is `if(a > 15)`

However, if this is just curiosity or a brain teaser exercise, it's certainly worth testing one's regex thought processes. I have included solutions below:

15 and above = `[1-9]\d{2,}|1[5-9]|[2-9]\d`

20 and above = `[1-9]\d{2,}|[2-9]\d`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For 15+ :

```
/^(?:[1][5-9]|(?:[2-9][0-9]+)|(?:[1-9][0-9][0-9]+))$/
```

For 20+ :

```
 /^((?:[2-9][0-9]+)|(?:[1-9][0-9][0-9]+))$/
```

You can test this regex on [this](http://rubular.com/) link.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package dev.dump;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Created by NikonDSL
 */
class NumberDiapasone2RegExp {
  private static final String invalidArgumentEmpty="Invalid argument \"{0}\" was found! {1}";
  private static final Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)-(\\d+)?$");
  private String src;
  private String result="";
  private Long left;
  private Long right;
  private boolean transform09ToD;

  public NumberDiapasone2RegExp(final String src) {
    this(src, false);
  }

  public NumberDiapasone2RegExp(final String src, final boolean transform09ToD) {
    this.transform09ToD=transform09ToD;
    if (src==null || src.trim().length()==0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format(invalidArgumentEmpty,
                                                                    src,
                                                                    "It cannot be empty."));
        if (src.indexOf("-")<0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format(invalidArgumentEmpty,
                                                                    src,
                                                                    "It is supposed to have \"-\"."));
        if (src.indexOf("-")!=src.lastIndexOf("-"))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format(invalidArgumentEmpty,
                                                                    src,
                                                                    "It is supposed to have only one \"-\"."));
    Matcher syntaxChecker=pattern.matcher(src);
    if (!syntaxChecker.find()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format(invalidArgumentEmpty,
                                                                src,
                                                                "It is supposed to be in format \"##-##\"."));
    }
    this.src=src;
    parseAndCheck();
    String theSameDigits="";
    //the same digit goes towards result
    if (left.toString().length()==right.toString().length()){
      for (int i=0; i<left.toString().length(); i++){
        if (i<right.toString().length() &&
            left.toString().charAt(i)==right.toString().charAt(i)){
          theSameDigits+=left.toString().charAt(i);
        }
      }
      if (theSameDigits.length()>0){
        this.src=this.src.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(theSameDigits),"");
        this.src=this.src.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("-"+theSameDigits),"-");
        parseAndCheck();
      }
    }
    result=glueParts(compact(transform09ToD, toParts()));    
    Matcher m=secondCompact.matcher(result);
    while (m.find()){
      result=m.group(1).replace("(","").replace(")","")+"["+m.group(2).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")+m.group(3).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")+"][0-9]";
      m.reset(result);
    }
    //compact squares again
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    Pattern squresP=Pattern.compile("(\\[(\\d|-)+\\])");
    m=squresP.matcher(result);
    while (m.find()) {
      m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(compactSquares(m.group(1))));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    result=sb.toString();
    result=result.replaceAll("\\[(\\d)-\\1\\]","$1");
    result=result.replaceAll("\\[(\\d)\\]","$1");
    result=result.replace("{1}","").replace("{0,1}","?");
    if (result.indexOf("|")>=0) result=theSameDigits+"("+result+")";
    else result=theSameDigits+result;
    if (result.startsWith("(") && result.endsWith(")")) result=result.substring(1, result.length()-1);
  }

  private static Pattern secondCompact=Pattern.compile("(.*)(\\[\\d-?\\d\\]|\\d)\\[0-9\\]\\|(\\[\\d-?\\d\\]|\\d)\\[0-9\\]");

  static List<String> compact(boolean transform09ToD, String... parts) {
      Set<String> unique=new HashSet<String>();
      List<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
      for (String part : parts){
          if (part==null || part.length()==0) continue;
          part=compactSquares(part);
          part=part.replaceAll("\\[(\\d)\\]","$1");
          if (part.indexOf("[0-9]")>=0){
              if (transform09ToD) part=part.replace("[0-9]","\\d");
          }
          //[0-3][0-9]|4[0-9]=>[0-34][0-9]
          //[023][0-9]|4[0-9]=>[0234][0-9]
          //[02345789]=>[02-57-9]
          Matcher m=secondCompact.matcher(part);
          if (m.find()){
              part=m.group(1).replace("(","").replace(")","")+"["+m.group(2).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")+m.group(3).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")+"][0-9]";
          }
          part=part.replaceAll("\\[(\\d)-\\1\\]","$1");
          if (unique.add(part)) result.add(part);
      }
      return result;
  }

  static String compactSquares(String src){
    boolean inSquares=false;
    if (src.startsWith("[") && src.endsWith("]")){
      inSquares=true;
      src=src.substring(1,src.length()-1);
    }
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    if (!src.contains("-")) {
      List<Integer> digits=new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for (int i=0; i<src.length();i++){
        digits.add(Integer.parseInt(""+src.charAt(i)));
      }
      Collections.sort(digits);
      for (Integer s : digits){
        sb.append(s);
      }
      src=sb.toString();
      sb.setLength(0);
    }
    int firstChar = -2;
    int lastChar = -2;
    int currentChar;
    for (int i=0; i<src.length(); i++) {
      currentChar=src.charAt(i);
      if (currentChar == lastChar + 1) {
        lastChar = currentChar;
        continue;
      }
      if (currentChar == '-' && i+1 < src.length()) {
        lastChar = src.charAt(i + 1) - 1;
        continue;
      }
      flush(sb, firstChar, lastChar);
      firstChar = currentChar;
      lastChar = currentChar;
    }
    flush(sb, firstChar, lastChar);
    return (inSquares?"[":"")+sb.toString()+(inSquares?"]":"");
  }

  private static void flush(StringBuffer sb, int firstChar, int lastChar) {
    if (lastChar<=0) return;
    if (firstChar==lastChar) {
      sb.append((char)firstChar);
      return;
    }
    if (firstChar+1==lastChar){
      sb.append((char)firstChar);
      sb.append((char)lastChar);
      return;
    }
    sb.append((char)firstChar);
    sb.append('-');
    sb.append((char)lastChar);
  }

  static String glueParts(List<String> parts) {
      if (parts==null || parts.isEmpty()) return "";
      if (parts.size()==1) return parts.get(0);
      StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder(128);
      for (String part : parts){
          result.append(part);
          result.append("|");
      }
      result.deleteCharAt(result.length()-1);
      return result.toString();
  }

  private String[] toParts() {
    List<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
    if (getNumberOfDigits(left)>2 || getNumberOfDigits(right)>2) {
      result.add(startPart(left));
    }
    long leftPart=left;
    long rightPart=right;
    if (!String.valueOf(left).matches("10*")) leftPart=toPower(left);
    if (!String.valueOf(right).matches("10*")) rightPart=toPower(right)/10;
    if (rightPart/leftPart>=10) {
      result.add(speedUpPart(left, right));
    }
    //for 1-2 digit process
    if (getNumberOfDigits(left)==1 && getNumberOfDigits(right)==1){
      result.add("["+left+"-"+right+"]");
    }
    else if (getNumberOfDigits(left)==1 && getNumberOfDigits(right)==2){
      if (0==Integer.parseInt(getMajorDigit(right))) {
        result.add(getMajorDigit(left)+
                   "["+
                   getMajorDigit(getNumberWithoutMajorDigit(left))+
                   "-"+
                   getMajorDigit(getNumberWithoutMajorDigit(right))+
                   "]");
      }
      else if (1==Integer.parseInt(getMajorDigit(right))) {
        result.add("["+
                   getMajorDigit(getNumberWithoutMajorDigit(left))+
                   "-9]");
        result.add(getMajorDigit(right)+
                   "[0-"+
                   getMajorDigit(getNumberWithoutMajorDigit(right))+
                   "]");
      }
      else if (2<=Integer.parseInt(getMajorDigit(right))) {
        result.add("["+
                   getMajorDigit(left)+
                   "-9]");
        result.add("[1-"+
                   (Integer.parseInt(getMajorDigit(right))-1)+
                   "][0-9]");
        result.add(getMajorDigit(right)+
                   "[0-"+
                   getMajorDigit(getNumberWithoutMajorDigit(right))+
                   "]");
      }
      else throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    else if (getNumberOfDigits(left)==2 && getNumberOfDigits(right)==2){
      if (Integer.parseInt(getMajorDigit(left))==Integer.parseInt(getMajorDigit(right))) {
        result.add(getMajorDigit(left)+
                   "["+
                   getMajorDigit(getNumberWithoutMajorDigit(left))+
                   "-"+
                   getMajorDigit(getNumberWithoutMajorDigit(right))+
                   "]");
      }
      else if (Integer.parseInt(getMajorDigit(left))+1==Integer.parseInt(getMajorDigit(right))) {
        result.add(getMajorDigit(left)+
                   "["+
                   getMajorDigit(getNumberWithoutMajorDigit(left))+
                   "-9]");
        result.add(getMajorDigit(right)+
                   "[0-"+
                   getMajorDigit(getNumberWithoutMajorDigit(right))+
                   "]");
      }
      else if (Integer.parseInt(getMajorDigit(left))+2<=Integer.parseInt(getMajorDigit(right))) {
        result.add(getMajorDigit(left)+
                   "["+
                   getMajorDigit(getNumberWithoutMajorDigit(left))+
                   "-9]");
        result.add("["+(Integer.parseInt(getMajorDigit(left))+1)+
                   "-"+(Integer.parseInt(getMajorDigit(right))-1)+
                   "][0-9]");
        result.add(getMajorDigit(right)+
                   "[0-"+
                   getMajorDigit(getNumberWithoutMajorDigit(right))+
                   "]");
      }
      else throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    else result.add(staticPart(right));
    result.add(breakPart(right));
    return result.toArray(new String[0]);
  }

  static String breakPart(final Long number) {
    if (getNumberOfDigits(number)<=2) {
      return "";
    }
    StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder(256);
    StringBuilder staticSection=new StringBuilder(32);
    staticSection.append(getMajorDigit(number));
    for (int i=1; i<getNumberOfDigits(number)-1; i++){
      if (i!=1) result.append("|");
      result.append(staticSection.toString());
      staticSection.append(String.valueOf(number).charAt(i));
      final long nextDigit=Long.parseLong(""+String.valueOf(number).charAt(i))-1;

      if (nextDigit<0) {
        result.setLength(0);
        result.append("|");
        continue;
      }
      if (nextDigit==0) result.append("0");
      else if (nextDigit==1) result.append("[01]");
      else result.append("[0-"+(nextDigit)+"]");
      final int numberOfRepeats=(getNumberOfDigits(number)-i-1);
      if (numberOfRepeats==1) result.append("[0-9]");
      else result.append("[0-9]{"+numberOfRepeats+"}");
    }
    //остаток - 2 последние цифры числа
    if (result.length()>0) {
      result.append("|");
      result.append(staticSection.toString());
      //последнюю цифру от 0 до нее
      result.append("[0-"+Long.parseLong(number.toString().replaceFirst("\\d+(\\d)","$1"))+"]");
    }
    if (result.length()>0) return result.toString().replace("||","|").replaceAll("^\\|","");
    return "";
  }

  static String staticPart(final Long number) {
    final long majorDigitMinus1=(Long.parseLong(getMajorDigit(number))-1);
    if (majorDigitMinus1<=0) return "";
    if (majorDigitMinus1==2) return "[1"+majorDigitMinus1+"][0-9]{"+(getNumberOfDigits(number)-1)+"}";
    else if (majorDigitMinus1==1) return "1[0-9]{"+(getNumberOfDigits(number)-1)+"}";
    return "[1-"+majorDigitMinus1+"][0-9]{"+(getNumberOfDigits(number)-1)+"}";
  }

  /**
   * [1-9][0-9]{<X-1>,<Y-1>}, where X-number of digits of less number, Y-number of digits of greater number
   */
  static String speedUpPart(Long left, Long right) {
    //найти ближайшее до 0 то есть для 23 найти 100 для 777 найти 1000
    //округленные до ближайшего 0
    if (!String.valueOf(left).matches("10*")) left=toPower(left);
    if (!String.valueOf(right).matches("10*")) right=toPower(right)/10;
    final int leftPartRepeat=getNumberOfDigits(left)+(String.valueOf(left).matches("10*")?0:1)-1;
    final int rightPartRepeat=getNumberOfDigits(right)+(String.valueOf(right).matches("10*")?0:1)-2;
    if (getNumberOfDigits(left)==1 && getNumberOfDigits(right)==2)
      return "[1-9]";
    else if (leftPartRepeat>=rightPartRepeat)
      return "[1-9][0-9]{"+rightPartRepeat+"}";
    else
      return "[1-9][0-9]{"+leftPartRepeat+","+rightPartRepeat+"}";
  }

  private static long toPower(final Long number) {
    final double dValue=Math.pow(10, getNumberOfDigits(number));
    final String value=String.format(Locale.US,"%24.0f",dValue);
    return Long.parseLong(value.replaceFirst("\\s*(\\d+)(\\D\\d+)?","$1"));
  }

  private static int getNumberOfDigits(long number){
    return (String.valueOf(number).length());
  }
  private static String getMajorDigit(long number){
    return (String.valueOf(number).substring(0,1));
  }
  private static long getNumberWithoutMajorDigit(long number){
    return Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(number).replaceFirst("\\d(\\d+)","$1"));
  }

  /**
   * f(<n>>2)=<major digit>(f(<n-1>)|[<major digit+1>-9][0-9]{<n-1>})
   */
  static String startPart(long number) {
    int i=getNumberOfDigits(number);
    if (i==1) {
      if (number==9) return "9";
      else if (number==8) return "[89]";
      return "["+number+"-9]";
    }
    final long majorPlusOne=Long.parseLong(getMajorDigit(number))+1;
    final int numberOfDigitsMinusOne=getNumberOfDigits(number)-1;
    String result = (majorPlusOne < 10 ? "(" : "");
    result+=getMajorDigit(number);
    result+=startPart(getNumberWithoutMajorDigit(number));
    result+=result.indexOf("|")<0 && majorPlusOne<10 && majorPlusOne!=numberOfDigitsMinusOne && numberOfDigitsMinusOne>1?"{"+numberOfDigitsMinusOne+"}":"";
    result+=(majorPlusOne < 10
             ? "|[" + majorPlusOne + "-9][0-9]"+(numberOfDigitsMinusOne > 1 ? "{" + numberOfDigitsMinusOne + "}" : "")
             : "");
    result+=(majorPlusOne < 10 ? ")" : "");
    return result;
  }

  private void parseAndCheck() {
    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(src);
    matcher.find();
    try{
      left=Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));
      right=Long.parseLong(matcher.group(2));
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
      left=right+1;
    }
    if (left>right){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format(invalidArgumentEmpty,
                                                              src,
                                                              "Left part must be less than right one."));
    }
  }

  public String getPattern() {
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.err.println(new NumberDiapasone2RegExp(args[0]).getPattern());
  }
}
```