# RegEx for number with in range 1 to 100000 with decimal

Tags: regex

RegEx for number with in range 1 to 100000 with decimal upto two digits.

-1, 0 should not be allowed.
1 to 100 000 allowed e.g. 1.00, 13.99, 100.45,9999.34, 99999.99, 100 000

Comment: In what language? What regex flavor?

Comment: And why do you want to use regex?

Comment: OP appears to be unwilling to read a regex description for his programming language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression number range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269448/regular-expression-number-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,4}(?:\.\d{1,2})?|100000|100000.00)$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/bY1yT2/2

Comment: Thanks ... But this should not allow 100000.01 to 100000.99

Comment: @AvinashRaj because the OP wanted it to be less than equal to 100000

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015788/regex-for-number-with-in-range-1-to-100000-with-decimal/26015863?noredirect=1#comment40747123_26015863

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex to match the numbers from 1 to 100000 with optional decimal upto two digits.

```
^(?:100000|[1-9]\d{0,4})(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bY1yT2/4)

- `\d{0,4}` Matches upto four digits.
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` Matches an Optional decimal and the following digits. Number of digits following must be 1 or 2.

Comment: Thanks ... But this should not allow 100000.01 to 100000.99

Comment: @KNB no. it allows that numbers also. See the demo link in my answer.