# How to validate input date in YYYY-MM-DD format inside the MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql

I have one DATE input parameter for a procedure ex: IN p_date DATE.I want to validate this input DATE parameter format inside a procedure which should be in YYYY-MM-DD format. If the input parameter is having characters or date format is wrong it should through an exception using SIGNAL.

Please find the below code what i written

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `validation_check`(IN pdate_time DATE)
BEGIN


DECLARE InputValidation CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
DECLARE dateValidation CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';

/*  Doing NULL validation  */
IF pdate_time IS NULL THEN
SIGNAL InputValidation
SET MESSAGE_TEXT='pdate_time should not be empty.';
END IF;

/*  Doing Date format validation
IF STR_TO_DATE(pdate_time,'%Y-%m-%d') != pdate_time THEN
SIGNAL dateValidation
SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Input Date format should be in YYYY-MM-DD.';
END IF;
*/
/*  Doing Date format validation  */
IF pdate_time NOT REGEXP '/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/' THEN
SIGNAL dateValidation
SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Input Date format should be in YYYY-MM-DD.';
END IF;

SELECT pdate_time;

END
```

Thanks,
Sagar

Comment: Can you please put your code you have so far in the question?

Comment: Out of curiosity: You specified the parameter to be `DATE`. Doesn't MySQL itself check whether the format is valid already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Regular expression will fail in this case, because they may only check date format, but not if it is a valid date (as, for example, `'2014-02-30'` has correct format but invalid data for date)

## Use string functions

**Concept**

The solution is - yes, use [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html). However, regular expressions will also be useful - to check if format was good, you still need to check date itself. Since validation of date is a single separated issue - you should create a function for it. That function will accept string and return result as boolean value - so either date is ok or not. This will be re-usable and, therefore, more flexible.

**Code**

Here we go with the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION VALIDATE_DATE(d VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
   DECLARE date_year  VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
   DECLARE date_month VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
   DECLARE date_day   VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
   DECLARE ym_delim   INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE md_delim   INT DEFAULT 0;
   -- First, if it's just not xxx-yyy-zzz format:
   SET ym_delim = LOCATE('-', d);
   SET md_delim = LOCATE('-', d, ym_delim+1);
   IF !ym_delim || !md_delim THEN

      RETURN FALSE;
   END IF;
   -- Second, if resulted members are not YYYY, MM or DD:
   SET date_year  = SUBSTR(d, 1, ym_delim-1);
   SET date_month = SUBSTR(d, ym_delim+1, md_delim-ym_delim-1);
   SET date_day   = SUBSTR(d, md_delim+1);
   IF  date_year  NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}$'
    || date_month NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}$'
    || date_day   NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}$' THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
   END IF;
   -- Finally, check if date itself is ok, like 2014-02-30 isn't ok:
   IF DATE(CONCAT(date_year, '-', date_month, '-', date_day)) IS NULL THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
   END IF;
   RETURN TRUE;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

As you can see, we have three cases, when date validating fails:

- First, if there are no proper delimiters (which are `-`). Then year, month and day just can't be found
- Second, if extracted year, month and day part are just bad (for instance, date was `foo-bar-baz`). That's why we can't use date functions to extract those parts and so we have to use string functions.
- Third - finally, if our date parts seems to be good, there still may be false result because of invalid combination (`2014-13-01` has wrong month, for example).

**Seems to be a solution**

There is, however, `STR_TO_DATE()` function which may look like solution. Unfortunately, it will pass date parts which are not in corresponding format (such as `2014-1-1`) - thus, it can't be used for direct format validation. That is why I used separate stored function instead.

## What will be passed

All `YYYY-MM-DD` dates, which are correct in terms of MySQL, **will be passed**. That is, early dates, such as `'0001-01-01'` **are correct** :

```
mysql> SELECT VALIDATE_DATE('0001-01-01');
+-----------------------------+
| VALIDATE_DATE('0001-01-01') |
+-----------------------------+
|                           1 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And, in fact, they should be correct, because they are valid for MySQL. However, such things as `001-01-01` won't be passed even despite fact, that such strings are correct for MySQL dates too:

```
mysql> SELECT VALIDATE_DATE('001-01-01'), DATE('001-01-01');
+----------------------------+-------------------+
| VALIDATE_DATE('001-01-01') | DATE('001-01-01') |
+----------------------------+-------------------+
|                          0 | 0001-01-01        |
+----------------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And that is derived from your **format expectations** - you should filter all the things, which do not have `YYYY-MM-DD` format exactly, thus, you'll have such results.

Comment: Hi Alma, thanks for your answer and i tested it, its working fine but you mentioned that "Regular expression will fail in this case, because they may only check date format, but not if it is a valid date (as, for example, '2014-02-30' has correct format but invalid data for date)". Is it not possible to check the date format and valid data using Regular expression?

Comment: It's possible. But it will be just hell. Actually, I've already had such issue (so, matching integer interval with regex) - you may check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374231/convert-integer-numeric-interval-to-regex) "Will fail" - I mean that it's not the thing which should be used. Besides, it you'll want to customize error message, single regex will not allow you to do it

Comment: Hi Alma, this function is accepting for date value '0000-00-00', any help

Comment: It will. And why should not it do that? `0000-00-00` is a _valid date for MySQL_

Comment: In my procedure if i get DATE value something like '2014-15-01' or 'anystring' then default date value is '0000-00-00'

Comment: I still am not sure why `0000-00-00` should be treated as invalid date, but if it should - just add it as a check into function (so, plain `IF` would be enough)

Comment: i added below condition in my procedure and now its working fine and many thanks for your help                                          IF DATE_FORMAT(pdate_time,'%Y-%m-%d')='0000-00-00' THEN
  SIGNAL InputValidation
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Input Date format should be in YYYY-MM-DD.';
  END IF;

Comment: is it just me? seems like this function create script won't run properly w/o DELIMITER //  in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

To validate dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION validate_date(date_string VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS BOOLEAN
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE valid_date BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE year_val INT;
    DECLARE month_val INT;
    DECLARE day_val INT;
    SET valid_date = TRUE;
    IF date_string NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$' THEN
        SET valid_date = FALSE;
    ELSE
        SET year_val = SUBSTR(date_string, 1, 4);
        SET month_val = SUBSTR(date_string, 6, 2);
        SET day_val = SUBSTR(date_string, 9, 2);
        IF (month_val < 1 OR month_val > 12) THEN
            SET valid_date = FALSE;
        ELSEIF (day_val < 1 OR day_val > DAY(LAST_DAY(CONCAT(year_val, '-', month_val, '-01')))) THEN
            SET valid_date = FALSE;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN valid_date;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Tests:

```sql
-- Good date.
SELECT validate_date('2023-01-01');
```

```sql
-- Bad date.
SELECT validate_date('2023-01-32');
```

```sql
-- Leap years even work.
SELECT validate_date('2024-02-29');
```